# Webservice returning list

Tags: linq, web-services, list, linq-to-sql

I have a webservice that returns `DataTable`, but instead of it I want to return a list. Is there a way to return a list directly from SQL or I would have to return it as a `DataTable` and then transform it to a list?

Comment: Do you have any code to show what you've tried so far?

Comment: @kolin I am at the stage of planning. Since this is not a stuck in a code question, rather then planning issue, I really didn't try anything other then hard thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is convert each row in your DataTable to an object.

Here is a nice blog post that shows a helper class for this: [Converting Custom Collections To and From DataTable](http://lozanotek.com/blog/archive/2007/05/09/Converting_Custom_Collections_To_and_From_DataTable.aspx)

The idea is that you loop trough all your rows and then use reflection to create the objects. You do this by mapping each column name to a corresponding property name.

You can also use Linq to DataSet to run a Linq query against your DataTable. In Linq you can then use Projection to transform your data into a new type.

Here are some examples: [Query Expression Syntax Examples: Projection (LINQ to DataSet)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386943.aspx)

Comment: So basically there is no shortcut between SQL to List using Linq for example?